# FastAPI - Using path parms with format strings

Tags: python, fastapi

I want to use path parameters along with format strings.

```py
prefix = 'api/v1'

@router.get(f'{prefix}/{item}')
def get_item(item: str):
    return ...
```

Here, python complains about there not being an `item` variable.
Replacing `f'{prefix}/{item}` with `'%s/{item}' % (prefix)` probably fixes it, but it looks quite ugly, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: If you don't want the format string to expand the `{`, use `{{`: `@router.get(f'{prefix}/{{item}}')`. This will give  the literal string `{item}` to the decorator function.

Comment: add prefix in your app `app.include_router(router, prefix=prefix)` and you can just write `@router.get("/{item}")`